# How to display JSON URL image in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, json, uicollectionview

I am getting JSON data which contains an image. I am showing that image on `UICollectionViewCell`, but i can't display the image on `UICollectionViewCell`. In JSON link this is data

```
{"pd_id":"244","pd_product_name":"Panasonic TH-22C400DX 55.88 cm (22) LED TV (Full HD)","pd_item_price":"11610","pd_item_mrp":"12110","pd_item_code":"TH-22C400DX","image":"product_1450855201.png"}
```

I am storing this image in NSObject class.

```
cell.ItemImageName.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mensObject.pd_item_image]];
```

`mensObect` is `NSObject` class and `pd_item_image` is `NSString`. How can I display image in `UICollectionView'?

Comment: Do you have an image in your Bundle named `product_1450855201.png`? Or is it the final path of a web image?

Comment: final path of a web image. please see the above dictionary, In this json "image":"product_1450855201.png"